# Understanding GStreamer Pipelines

Tags: c, gstreamer

I have a sort of abstract question, along with a concrete example. I'm just now starting to work with GStreamer and I'm trying to understand the flow of pipelines. I want to have a good intuition for what kind of elements should exist in my pipeline for any given task. I recently completed a tutorial using a tee to display a video representation of test audio ([link here](http://docs.gstreamer.com/display/GstSDK/Basic+tutorial+7%3A+Multithreading+and+Pad+Availability)). Now, I'm trying to get GStreamer to play an .ogg file and display a similar graphical representation. I must be thinking about this wrong, but I looked up a way to construct an ogg pipeline and found

```
sudo gst-launch-0.10 filesrc file.ogg ! oggdemux ! vorbisdec ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! autoaudiosink
```

So, I constructed a pipeline using a Tee as such:

```
if (gst_element_link_many (data.audio_source, data.tee, NULL) != TRUE) {
  g_printerr ("Elements #1 could not be linked.\n");
  linked = FALSE;
}
if (gst_element_link_many (data.audio_queue, data.oggdemux, data.vorbisdec, data.audio_convert, data.audio_resample, data.audio_sink, NULL) != TRUE) {
  g_printerr ("Elements #2 could not be linked.\n");
  linked = FALSE;
}
if (gst_element_link_many (data.video_queue, data.visual, data.video_convert, data.video_sink, NULL) != TRUE) {
  g_printerr ("Elements #3 could not be linked.\n");
  linked = FALSE;
}
```

But I get an error telling me "Elements #2 could not be linked, but I'm not sure why that pattern is not allowed. Please help! Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to place oggdemux before audio_queue? This seems to be common practice in GStreamer.

Comment: Linking data.audio_source -> data.oggdemux -> data.tee, if that's what you mean, cannot be done either

Comment: No, I meant `audio_source->tee` just like you have in the code (Elements  #1), *but* Elements #2 would be `oggdemux->audio_queue->vorbisdec->...`.

Comment: Same error for: data.oggdemux, data.audio_queue, data.vorbisdec, data.audioconvert, data.audioresample, data.autoaudiosink

Comment: What about: `oggdemux->vorbisdec->audio_queue->...`? Is the `audio_queue` even needed? Have you tried to link the elements individually (and see where linking fails)?

Comment: data.oggdemux, data.vorbisdec, data.audio_queue, data.audioconvert, data.audioresample, data.autoaudiosink also fails. I split the gst_element_link calls into individual ones, and found that it was having trouble linking oggdemux to vorbisdec, but I have no idea why, because it works in the ogg pipline example that I found and ran above.

Comment: This is a minor nitpick, but in your initial command line example for gst-launch, it should not be necessary to preface the command with 'sudo'. You should be able to do this as an unprivileged user.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is working on this, head over to http://docs.gstreamer.com/display/GstSDK/Playback+tutorial+6%3A+Audio+visualization. Also, if you want to specify a local file using playbin2, just set the `uri` parameter to `file:///myfile.ogg`.

Comment: Also, the reason that oggdemux and vorbisdec wouldn't link is because you cannot directly link a demuxer and a decoder. The demuxer does not have pads to begin with, and only creates pads when data begins streaming through it, so you need to create an signal handler to add the pad when the "pad-added" signal is called.